# WPF TabControl - How to remove Margin above inactive Tabs?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Any Ideas how to remove the Margin in the following image?

[image: Tab Margin Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checked it via Snoop. By default, the selected `TabItem` has a margin of `-2,-2,-2,-1`, so you can set this top margin for all tab items:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-2,0,0"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Make sure you do `<Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal that's a good idea in case non-default styles are already active. Edited answer